# Abysmal performance with vectors in c++

Tags: c++, vector

**Disclaimer:** i just started programming in c++.

---

So i made a little program in c++ using SFML where i have 300 particles stored in a vector that are attracted to each other.

The program runs at 17 FPS!! i tried doing the same using a standard array and it didn't run much faster.

The same code in java using the Array libgdx class runs at 5000 FPS.
Using the java.util.Vector class runs at 2000 FPS.

Debugging i found out that most of the delay comes from retrieving an element from the vector.

I know i'm doing something wrong in that regard, so i would be grateful if someone can help me out.

Here is the update loop.

```
void update(RenderWindow& window) {
    window.clear();

    for (size_t i = 0, size = particles.size(); i != size; ++i) {
        Particle &part = particles[i];

        glm::vec2 forceSum;

        for (size_t j = 0, size = particles.size(); j != size; ++j) {
            Particle &part2 = particles[j];
            if (j == i) 
                continue;

            glm::vec2 v1 = part.getPos() - part2.getPos();
            glm::vec2 v2 = glm::normalize(v1);

            if (glm::length(v1) < 50)
                forceSum += (v2 * -0.1f);
        }

        part.applyForce(forceSum);
        part.update();

        shape.setPosition(part.getPos().x, part.getPos().y);
        window.draw(shape);
    }

    window.display();
}
```

I can show more code if requested.

Thanks in advance!

---

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"


using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

void update(RenderWindow& window);

int t = 0;
CircleShape shape(4);

vector<Particle> particles;

int main() {
    ContextSettings settings;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 16;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800, 800), "test", Style::Default, settings);

    shape.setFillColor(Color(155, 155, 155, 124));
    srand(4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
        Particle particle = Particle(glm::vec2(rand() % 800, rand() % 800), rand() % 10);
        particles.push_back(particle);
    }

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        update(window);
    }
    return 0;
}

void update(RenderWindow& window) {
    window.clear();

    for (size_t i = 0, size = particles.size(); i != size; ++i) {
        Particle &part = particles[i];

        glm::vec2 forceSum;

        for (size_t j = 0, size = particles.size(); j != size; ++j) {
            Particle &part2 = particles[j];
            if (j == i) 
                continue;

            glm::vec2 v1 = part.getPos() - part2.getPos();
            glm::vec2 v2 = glm::normalize(v1);

            if (glm::length(v1) < 50)
                forceSum += (v2 * -0.1f);
        }

        part.applyForce(forceSum);
        part.update();

        shape.setPosition(part.getPos().x, part.getPos().y);
        window.draw(shape);
    }

    window.display();
}
```

Particle.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Particle {
public:
    Particle(glm::vec2 pos, float m);
    void update();
    void applyForce(const glm::vec2 &fce);
    void setPos(const glm::vec2 &pos);
    void setV(const glm::vec2 &vel);
    const glm::vec2 getPos();
    const glm::vec2 getV();
private:
    float mass;
    glm::vec2 acceleration = glm::vec2(0, 0);
    glm::vec2 position = glm::vec2(0, 0);
    glm::vec2 velocity = glm::vec2(0, 0);
};
```

Particle.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Particle.h"
#include <iostream>

using glm::vec2;

Particle::Particle(vec2 pos, float m) {
    mass = m;
    position = pos;
}

void Particle::update() {
    velocity += acceleration;
    if (position.x + velocity.x > 800 || position.x + velocity.x < 0 ||     position.y + velocity.y > 800 || position.y + velocity.y < 0) {
        velocity.x = 0; velocity.y = 0;
    }
    position += velocity;
}

void Particle::applyForce(const vec2 &fce) {
    acceleration = fce/mass;
}

void Particle::setPos(const vec2 &pos) {
    position = pos;
}

void Particle::setV(const vec2 &vel) {
    velocity = vel;
}

const vec2 Particle::getV() {
    return velocity;
}


const vec2 Particle::getPos() {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Just making sure, you compiled your C++ code with optimizations turned on right?

Comment: Please share the compiler flags or project configuration you are using.

Comment: P.S: minor optimization, compare the square length instead of the length, you save a square root op which isnt entirely cheap.

Comment: "i found out that most of the delay comes from retrieving an element from the vector." - I'm truly curious how you drew that conclusion. Your posted code obviously has an O(N^2) nested loop construct, so that above anything else would seem the most expensive prime driver of this algorithm, *especially* if something expensive is being done for each inner iteration.

Comment: Ok, tried with optimizations, i can only use the /ox flag if i compile with 'release'. Its running at 600 fps now, better, but still not there.

Comment: I drew that conclussion from the fact that i tried removing all the code from the loop except from the 'Particle &part = particles[i];' and 'Particle &part2 = particles[j];', and the fps remained the same.

Comment: @Joeav What do you get if you use `/O2` for the optimization level?

Comment: Well you didn't have optimizations turned on, so any conclusions you made weren't valid. All those indexing operators probably had debug assertions in them making them slower. Use a profiler of some sort, if you use Visual Studio it has one.

Comment: @Joeav If your fps remained the same when you're only doing vector dereferencing, that hints at a problem somewhere else, possibly with rendering. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: @FredLarson I think the inner loop is fine, this seems like a [Boids simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boids) each particle is affected by all other particles (except itself ofc) so its definitely O(N^2). I've done something similar on GPU using compute shaders.

Comment: @Borgleader: Yeah, you're probably right. Comment removed.

Comment: @FredLarson no, because i add the force each other particle inflicts on the current one.

Comment: "Its running at 600 fps now, better, but still not there" - why would you need more than 600fps? The human eye can't even percieve much above 60. How on earth can 600fps not be "good enough" (or rather; overkill)?

Comment: @Borgleader ok, ill try to add more code. The only thing i do for each iteration is add the velocity and the bounds of the screen.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl if something works 6 times as fast in java, im doing something wrong. I dont care about about the FPS, trying to learn c++ from my mistakes.

Comment: I believe your problem is elswhere, maybe in the draw() funcrion.  Why don't you use iterators?  Also, you compute twice the length of v1. Once when normalizing, once for the test, v2 is not used oustide of the successful test block.  These are not enough to justify such at performance hit.  std::vector in release mode is very fast.  I'd have a very close look at window.draw.  You could also use a profiler.

Comment: Full code is up

Comment: Do your vectors use dynamic memory as well, or are they declared at a kind of struct { float x, y; }; type ?  It could be a caching issue.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy glm::vec2 is just float x,y;

Comment: You call `particles.size()` a *lot* (every time through multiple loops), but the size of the container doesn't change, so maybe just call it *once* outside the loops and store it in a `const` variable and use that instead.

Comment: vector.size() is inlined and is a int read.

Comment: @Michaël Roy: sure, but if you do it enough times it still adds up.

Comment: The compiler usually puts it in a register, even in the case `for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)`  because it's declared `const`

Comment: If you compiled your graphics library yourself, are you sure *that* library was compiled with optimizations enabled?

Comment: @Joeav have you tried to remove `window.draw(shape)` in a release build ?  on vs you need both -Ox and -DNDEBUG.;   If by any chance you have -D_DEBUG set for a release configuration, you'd still have all kinds of error checking code enabled in the std libraries.

Comment: @Michaël Roy Running at 730 FPS currently, 800 FPS if removing `window.draw(shape)`. Also tried with iterators, didnt help either. Will try with standard arrays now that i have optimizations.

Comment: How many particles do you have?  and which compiler?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy The question clearly states "300 particles".

Comment: @Michaël Roy 300 particles, as i said, same code and same amount of particles give 5000fps in java (libgdx). Im compiling with visual studio community 2017

Comment: @Joeav can you test it without rendering? You are using CircleShape, you can specify amount of vertices per circle. 1. You are making 300 draw calls each frame, (each of which has tens of vertices), where libgdx may batch them into one (use vertex array for things like this). 2. do 3 loops instead of one, separate all steps to reduce amount of cache misses (first calculate and apply force, second update, third draw).

Comment: @Sopel now that the other problems have been solved, it seems that removing the draw call does increase the frames from 1.5k to 3k and yes, i think libgdx batchs them. About 2 i'm going to try, that's new to me, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've ran a vs studio profiler session on your code.

The app spends 59% of its time calculating square roots.  You should optimize your code as follow:

```
    glm::vec2 v1 = part.getPos() - part2.getPos();
    glm::vec2 v2 = glm::normalize(v1);     // <- 1 square root computed here

    if (glm::length(v1) < 50)              // <- another one here
        forceSum += (v2 * -0.1f);
```

Becomes:

```
    glm::vec2 v1 = part.getPos() - part2.getPos();
    float l = glm::dot(v1, v1);
    if (l < 2500)
    {
        forceSum += (v1 / sqrt(l));
    }

 }  // end inner loop
 part.applyForce(forceSum * .1f);
```

This will divide the time spent calculating square roots by 2 or more.

With null vec2s this optimization made execution on my machine go from 38s/10000 frames to 7s/10000 frames.

Thanks to BorgLeader and Rabbid76, who helped optimize your code further.

Comment: `if (glm::dot(v1, v1) < 2500)` is a shorter way of saying the same thing and has the advantage of not needing to change if v1 becoms a vec3 (for wtv reason).

Comment: The multiplication by `* -0.1f` can be done outside the loop.

Comment: Sure.  But these will never compare in scale to a square root.  As a reminder, floating point multiplication on modern x86 cpus is even faster than integer multiplication.

Comment: That greatly increased the fps to 1500, did the same trick in java and it hit 6000 fps. Thanks for all the help guys, ill see what else i can do.

Comment: Moving the call to window.draw(shape); to its own loop may help improve memory cache access.